# File I/O loop breaking prematurely?

Tags: scala, for-loop

I'm reading a file line by line using this loop:

```
for(line <- s.getLines()){
  mylist += otherFunction(line);
}
```

where the variable `mylist` is a `ArrayBuffer` which stores a collection of custom datatypes. The `otherFunction(line);` does something like this...

```
def otherFunction(list:String)={
  val line = s.getLine(index);
  val t = new CustomType(0,1,line(0));
  t
}
```

and `CustomType` is defined as...

```
class CustomType(name:String,id:Int,num:Int){}
```

I've ommitted much of the code as you can see because it's not relevant. I can run the rest of my functions and it'll read the file line by line till EOF as long as I comment out the last line of `otherFunction()`. Why is returning a value in this function to my list causing my for loop to stop?

Comment: As written `otherFunction` returns `Unit` so it's probably not doing what you want. Also from experience, source of errors tends to lies in what people think is not relevant. It's easier to help if you reduce your code to the bare compilable snippet.

Comment: @huynhji I've updated my code to reflect your request.

Comment: You have ommitted the type of of `s` as well, which might be rather important...

Comment: as written, otherFunction still does not make sense. It ignores its arguments and it uses s directly.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do here. I assume `s` is a `scala.io.Source` object. Why does `otherFunction` take a string argument that it doesn't use? `getLine` is deprecated, and you don't say where `index` comes from. Do you really want to refer to the first character in the line String with index 0, and is it really supposed to be an `Int`? Assuming that this is actually what you want to do, why not just use a `map` on the iterator?

```
val list = s.getLines.map(i => new CustomType("0", 1, i(0).asDigit)).toIndexedSeq
```